# $_GET search forms, with Jquery highlighting

Tags: php, jquery

I made my first search form on WordPress using the following

```
<form action="/searchstock"><input name="stock" type="text" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" /></form>
```

and on the search page, I added the following...

```
<?php } else

{


                    $args = array (

    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'available_no',
            'value'     => $_GET['stock'],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        ),
        ),
    'number'         => '20',

);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// The User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        // do something
        echo '<strong><p>'. $user->display_name .' |  <a href="/profile/'. $user->user_nicename .'">View Profile</a></p></strong> <p>'. $user->available_no . '</p><br>';
    }
} else {
    // no users found
}

}

?>
```

Now I'm looking for a way to highlight the search results. So I tried going to [this tutorial post](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html), but I can't seem to get how to get jQuery to work with my PHP scripts.